# Modify field annotation based on condition of another

Tags: java, swagger

here is simple java class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Response {

    @Schema(required = true)
    private Long id;
    
    @Schema(required = true, enumAsRef = true)
    private ChannelType type;
         
    @Schema(required = true, nullable = true)
    private Mailing mailing;

    // ...
}
```

and what I need to do
if `type == EMAIL` I should do this

```java
@Schema(required = true)
private Mailing mailing;
```

if type != EMAIL  I should do this

```java
@Schema(required = true, nullable = true)
private Mailing mailing;
```

it means if type is email filed mailing cant be null and in other ways it can null

is there any way to do it without do java inherit classes

Comment: I don't think such conditions can be expressed using annotations. It's best to keep `nullable=true` and check for nulls elsewhere.

Comment: @Helen thanks you , i think its realy the single good idea